# C shell - getting jobs in the background to report status once done

Tags: linux, unix, csh

I implemented a simple c shell to take in commands like `sleep 3 &`. I also implemented it to "listen" for sigchild signals once the job complete.

But how do I get the job id and command to be printed out like the ubuntu shell once it is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against catching `SIGCHLD` signals.

A neater way to do that is to call [`waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) with the `WNOHANG` option. If it returns `0`, you know that the job with that particular pid is still running, otherwise that process has terminated and you fetch its exit code from the `status` parameter, and print the message accordingly.

Moreover, bash doesn't print the job completion status at the time the job completes, but rather at the time when the next command is issued, so this is a perfect fit for `waitpid`.

A small disadvantage of that approach is that the job process will stay as a zombie in the period between its termination and the time you call `waitpid`, but that probably shouldn't matter for a shell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the child pid (from the fork) and the command executed in your shell (in some sort of table or map structure).  Then, when you get a SIGCHILD, you find the child pid and that gives you the corresponding command.